# Raspberry Pi Zero Internet connection through USB for linux OS

Tags: usb, internet

I connected my Pi Zero to my PC ( Linux LMDE 3 Cindy) via USB port successfully, SO i want to connect to internet via my laptop which is connected to internet by its WIFI.

I found [this instruction](http://www.circuitbasics.com/raspberry-pi-zero-ethernet-gadget/) or [this question via raspberrypi.stackexchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/11684/how-can-i-connect-my-pi-directly-to-my-pc-and-share-the-internet-connection) but those are working for window or MAC OS,but i don't find it for Linux!!!!

SO i need the similar instruction for enabling sharing my internet via USB `enp0s20f0u1` device (PI Zero) in Linux. for example in windows we need to :

> In the WiFi Properties window, click on the “Sharing” tab : similar to
>   this photo:

[image: WiFi internet sharing]

So in Linux version what is the similar instruction to doing this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your question seems to be about sharing an Internet connection in as desktop Linux. To what it is shared, the Pi, is irrelevant in this context.

Comment: I want to share my laptop internet to my raspberry which is connected to my laptop via USB Port. I found the way's for windows OS but not for Linux OS. SO i asked here.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. The Raspberry Pi is NOT the issue then, it's irrelevant, as I previously commented. For general Linux questions there's [unix.se] (make sure to post all the relevant  information about your distro and version). Your question is about *sharing an Internet connection in a desktop Linux. To what it's shared DOESN'T MATTER.* The Raspberry Pi needs no special configuration for that, there's nothing RPi specific in using a shared internet connection.

Comment: This is exactly the same situation as commented in https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/11684/how-can-i-connect-my-pi-directly-to-my-pc-and-share-the-internet-connection#comment15836_11684 , replace Windows by Linux and it's exactly the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

here you could find good suggestion [here](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget.pdf) :

as it said on page 16 add this to   /etc/network/interfaces ( by `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`):

```
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
   wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug usb0
iface usb0 inet static
        address 192.168.7.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.7.0
        broadcast 192.168.7.255
        gateway 192.168.7.1
```

After that Save the file and run

```
sudo ifdown usb0
```

(this may fail, its fine)

```
sudo ifup usb0
ifconfig usb0
```

unplug pi and then connect it to usb again .it'll probably be set up for DHCP by default so change it to Configure IP4 Manually:

> For the IP address pick  192.168.7.1 (note that this is not the same
>
> as the Pi Zero's address!)  For the subnet mask, use 255.255.255.0
>
> (same as Pi) For the router/gateway use 192.168.7.1 (same as Pi)

If you didn't use our suggested netconfig above on the Pi, you may have to adjust this one to Linux similar to this:
[image]

and then you could run `sudo ssh pi@192.168.7.2` to connect to that, second part is could be done easier and you must configure your mode, to share internet with this IP (**192.168.7.2**)  and i will write tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Based of [this](https://www.slideshare.net/GSHCO/raspberry-zero-usb-in-linux) PowerPoint slide, then next step is doing this commands in Linux like this:

[image]

```
sudo ifconfig enp0s20f0u2 192.168.7.1
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface wlp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface enp0s20f0u2 -j ACCEP
```

The **enp0s20f0u2** is the USB port of Raspberry Pi Zero, and 192.168.7.1 is the IP Address of the USB by this setting:

[image]

Comment: The first picture serves no apparent purpose, because you included the relevant commands in the answer already. I would remove it.