# How to connect raspberry pi Zero (non-W) to internet through usb cable?

Tags: networking, pi-zero

The model i have doesn't support wifi (don't have the wifi adapter) as it's the non-W model.

I managed to once do tethering with a usb cable, but I forgot how i did it (it was a while ago and i never took notes)

How can i connect my rpi0 to internet by using a usb cable (one connected to the rpi0, the other end to a computer which is already connected to internet)?

I don't want to have to buy anything to achieve this. I'm also well aware of the slow speed that USB would give for an internet connection.

PS: I'm using Linux on the computer i mentioned in my example.

Comment: Didn't this come up in your search https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98790/raspberry-pi-zero-internet-connection-through-usb-for-linux-os

Comment: This has been asked multiple times. Please search for [OTG gadget ethernet](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=OTG+gadget+ethernet).

Comment: this did, but it seems it wasn't working...guess I'll either edit this post or post another one with more details :)

Comment: You have posted a question with more details https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/117187/79866. Please delete this one.