# Unable to connect Pi to PC via Ethernet and share Wifi/Internet

Tags: networking, windows

I am trying to use my Raspberry Pis internet connection to share it with my old PC (which only has an ethernet port) using the following article

[Connect Pi to PC via ethernet and share internet connection](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/11684/how-can-i-connect-my-pi-directly-to-my-pc-and-share-the-internet-connection)

but when I try using the internet on my PC it gives me the error `No internet connection` After running troubleshooting I get the error `"Ethernet" does not have a valid IP configuration.`

Why is this the case? Do I have to change my internet settings on my Pi or does it have something to do with the PC?

**Additional Info:**

**Raspberry Pi**: **OS**: Raspbian **Model**: 3B

**Windows PC OS**: Windows 10 Version 1803 (Build 17134.407)

Comment: So, you want to share your PC's internet connection with your Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Which Pi? Is it a new-ish one with Wi-fi? How is your MS-Windows PC connected to the internet?

Comment: This is a question about Windows

Comment: @Milliways How so? Isn't it about the Pi IP config?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor It is a Pi 3B. And my Windows PC isn't connected to the internet that is why I am trying to connect the Pi via Ethernet in order for the PC to get internet via the Pi.

Comment: @GramThanos No, I want to share the Pi's internet connection with the PC

Comment: If the question is about sharing Pi internet you should ask a clear question about that, no need to mention Windows. I don't see how anyone could read that into your question.

Comment: @Milliways Ok. I have updated the post to make it more clear. Is there anything else I should add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote in a comment: "*I want to share the Pi's internet connection with the PC*". At the answer to the question you have linked I find: "*5. Now your Pi will obtain an IP address from your PC and can access internet through your PC*". This is not what you want, you are using the wrong setup.

Because you use a Raspberry Pi 3B I assume you are connected to a local internet router by wifi. Now you have to make the RasPi a router so it routes data between the wifi interface and the wired interface to the PC. How to do it you can look at [Can a Raspberry Pi Zero W be turned into an USB WiFi dongle to any USB Host like x86 PC or mini-PC?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/98017/79866). Please follow there the section **Use routing**.